# Need Regex for MM/yyyy

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for for MM/yyyy. I need to validate only month and year and enforce the user to just enter date like 01/1999 etc...

Comment: What range of valid years should be checked for?

Answer (score 4):

`^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/\d{4}$`

Note that this only checks for month. One can enter years like 0000 or 9999. The check for this can be implemented with a few regex constructs, depending on your constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `\d\d/\d\d\d\d` or `\d{2}/\d{4}` or `^\d{2}/\d{4}$`

Comment: Don't you have to escape the slash?

Comment: A backslash literal has to be escaped.

Comment: This will accept 20/2010, which is hardly a valid month/year combination.

Comment: @Fredrik: Agreed. This is just a syntactic validation. For a validation with a bit of date semantics it's better to use the regex by @battal.

Comment: @lvarska: Whether or not slash literals have to be escaped depends on the language in use. Since the question didn't specify the language, the correct approach is to leave them out since the slash doesn't have to be escaped *to the RE engine*.

Answer (score 0):

`\d{2}/\d{4}` or `\d\d/\d\d\d\d`

Comment: This will accept 20/2010, which is hardly a valid month/year combination.